# Values of $\cos(\arg(z))$ subject to the constraints $\arg(z) > \arg(z + 1)$ and $\arg(z) >\arg(z+ i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be any complex number such that its real and imaginary parts are both non-zero. Further, suppose that z satisfies the relations $\arg(z) > \arg(z + 1)$ and $\arg(z) > \arg(z+ i)$. Then $\cos(\arg(z))$ can take

(a) Any value in the set $(-1/2, 0)\cup (0, 1/2)$ but none from outside

(b) Any value in the interval $(-1, 0)$ but none from outside

(c) Any value in the interval $(0, 1)$ but none from outside

(d) Any value in the set $(-1, 0)\cup(0, 1)$ but none from outside.

In the interval $[0, \pi], \cos x$ is decreasing so $\cos(\arg(z)) < \cos(\arg(z + 1))$ and $\cos(\arg(z)) < \cos(\arg(z+ i))$.
How to proceed? Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to proceed will be using a graph.

Given equations:
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x+1}\right)>0\\ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(y+1\right)}{x}\right)>0$$

[image]

The above can be plotted out pretty easily by throwing in values. The most one can do is to solve $\tan ^{-1}a- \tan ^{-1}b$.

The common region (in purple) represents where complex number $z$ can be present. To sum up the question, find the maximum and minimum argument of a complex number in the $\textrm{purple}$ region presented in the graph above.